# Why is this simple code throwing a TansactionTooLargeException?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, random, countdowntimer

So here is the deal. I have a game I am creating and it has a countdown timer and a random number generator. Simple. Well I have the game working 100% but I keep getting a crash when the count down timer gets to the very last tick.. sometimes and I mean sometimes. I was getting a java.lang.OutOfMemory error but I have narrowed it down to this bit of code but it is throwing a TansactionTooLargeException but both errors happen at the same point, the very last tick.

Again this can happen after the countdown timer runs once or 500+, it is very random and makes no sense.

FirstClass.java code

```
package com.example.testingclasses;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstClass extends Activity {

    TextView thenumber;
    int min, max;
    ProgressBar gameTimer;
    CountDownTimer gameCountDownTimer;
    int i1, cdt,   progress ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_class);
        FirstClass.this.random();
    }

    public void random(){ //random number generator and displayer
        TextView thenumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.thenumber);
            min = 1;
            max = 5;
            cdt = 2500;
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.thenumber)).setClickable(true);
            Random r = new Random();
            i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;        
            thenumber.setText(Integer.toString(i1));
            FirstClass.this.setTimer(cdt);
    }


    public void setTimer(int time) {
        gameTimer = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.timetoclick);
        progress = 100;
        final int actualTime = time;
        gameTimer.setProgress(progress);
        gameCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(actualTime, 10) {
            int totalTime = actualTime;
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    progress = (int)((millisUntilFinished ) /(double)totalTime * 100);
                    gameTimer.setProgress(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //progress = 0;
                //gameTimer.setProgress(progress);
                if (progress == 0) {
                    FirstClass.this.random();   
            }   else {
                gameCountDownTimer.onFinish();
            }
          }
        }; 
        gameCountDownTimer.start();
    }   
}
```

activity_first_class.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testingclasses.FirstClass" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thenumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timetoclick"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="#"
        android:textSize="200sp"
        android:background="#00000000" />

     <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/timetoclick"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:progress="0" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the crash:

```
12-20 11:57:30.594: E/JavaBinder(18000): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
12-20 11:57:30.595: E/AndroidRuntime(18000): Error reporting crash
12-20 11:57:30.595: E/AndroidRuntime(18000): android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
12-20 11:57:30.595: E/AndroidRuntime(18000):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
12-20 11:57:30.595: E/AndroidRuntime(18000):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
12-20 11:57:30.595: E/AndroidRuntime(18000):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4100)
12-20 11:57:30.595: E/AndroidRuntime(18000):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:89)
12-20 11:57:30.595: E/AndroidRuntime(18000):    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
12-20 11:57:30.595: E/AndroidRuntime(18000):    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

I am trying to use the Eclipse memory analysis but haven't had any luck getting it to work.

Comment: Unlikely that the problem is in the code shown.

Comment: it is the only code running. What I posted is crashing. My original game was running fine but all of a sudden started getting the crash. I am testing on a Nexus 5 that just got the 5.0.1 update. Even though the code should not be crashing.

Comment: There is nothing in this code that would generate that exception. You only get that exception from some sort of inter-process communication (IPC), such as starting an activity with extras that are too large.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is throwing a StackOverflowError in this line: `gameCountDownTimer.onFinish();`.
This is a recursive call to onFinish method.

Comment: I added that because of a loop issue. It seemed that sometimes onFinish would happen before progress=0. Also note that I removed that line and just ran the code again and now the loop issue occurrs. There is one tick left and the loop get stuck.

Comment: replaced the code with gameCountDownTimer.cancel();
             progress = 0;
             gameTimer.setProgress(progress);
             MainActivity.this.random();     that seems to have fixed both of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the onFinish() code with.

```
gameCountDownTimer.cancel();
progress = 0;
gameTimer.setProgress(progress);
FirstClass.this.random();
```

fixed the loop issue I had in my game and the issue seen here.

The original issue of onTick not finishing before the onFinish() runs is still there but I am no longer getting my original issue and the fail posted here with the code above.

Actually an odd thing. This code works fine on my Nexus 5 but my Digital2 tablet I am still getting what appears like double clicks/unfinished onFinish. Investigating.